# Angular 6, ngFor identifier not defined

Tags: html, node.js, angular, typescript

I'm using Google's youtube API, and while I retrieve the data successfully, I'm unable to display it in a meaningful way. I use a service for the API call and the code is as follows. I'm trying to show a list of specific results I get from the API, such as name, description, and thumbnails.

**videos.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Videolist} from '../Models/videolist.model';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class VideosService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    public query: string;
    results = new Array();

    getVideos() {
        const finalURL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=*myapikey*&part=snippet' +
            ',id&order=date&maxResults=8&q=' + this.query;
        return this.http.get<Videolist>(finalURL);
    }
}
```

**videolist.model.ts**

```
import {Deserialize} from './deserialize.model';

export class Videolist implements Deserialize<Videolist> {
    videoId: string;
    description: string;
    thumbnails: any;

    deserialize(input: any): Videolist {
        Object.assign(this, input);
        return this;
    }
}
```

**topbar.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {VideosService} from '../services/videos.service';
import {ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-topbar',
    templateUrl: './topbar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./topbar.component.css'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class TopbarComponent {
    id = '2r5IbVJRvH4';
    private player;
    public ytEvent;
    public token: string;

    constructor(public data: VideosService) {
    }

    searchForm() {
        this.data.getVideos().subscribe(data => {
            this.data.results = data['items'];
            console.log(this.data.results);
        });
```

**topbar.component.html**

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" class="margin">
    <mat-toolbar>
        <form class="example-form">
            <mat-form-field class="testi">
                <input id="haku" matInput placeholder="Search for songs" [(ngModel)]="data.query" name="query">

            </mat-form-field>
            <button (click)="searchForm()" mat-button style="margin-left: 40px !important;"><mat-icon matSuffix>search</mat-icon></button>
        </form>
    </mat-toolbar>
</div>
<div class="container" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center start" class="keskii">
        <mat-card class="vasen">
            <mat-list>
                <mat-list-item *ngFor="let video of data.results"></mat-list-item>
                <h3 matLine> {{ video.description }}</h3>
            </mat-list>
```

I'm using `[(ngModel)]` for two-way data binding on the query, then click a button that uses the function `searchForm()` from my topbarcomponent.ts, which gets the results I want via the service. But if I try to loop through `data.results (*ngFor="let video of data.results")`, I get the error that **`video is undefined`**.
Is my model incorrect, am I trying to loop through the results incorrectly? If you didn't notice yet, I'm a total beginner when it comes to this.

Comment: Have you tried using ngIf until your response is  back?

Comment: I have, but the issue persists. Replied to the other reply in detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your results won't be available until the HTTP request completes. They will be undefined until then. Lopping over undefined just does not work :)

I suggest you wrap it in an *ngIf until the results are available like this:

```
<mat-list *ngIf="data.results">
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let video of data.results"></mat-list-item>
  <h3 matLine> {{ video.description }}</h3>
</mat-list>
```

You could show some alternative content whilst the results are undefined also using *ngIf

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Tried this but I still get "cannot read property 'description' of undefined. And {{ video.description }} shows video as undefined in the IDE already. I was under the assumption that ngFor would not require declaring "video", but I must be mistaken

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't show anything,  {{ video | json }} still shows "identifier 'video' is not defined in the IDE.

Comment: if it is not showing anything then it suggests video is undefined. What is coming back from the HTTP request? is the HTTP request setting data.results as expected?

Comment: this is what I get from the HTTP request: https://imgur.com/NdqTu2I
so to my knowledge the http request is setting data.results as expected. Also ngFor seems to create the correct amount of elements, but my way of viewing specific data seems to be incorrect as nothing shows.

Comment: `ngFor` just renders the element and it's children for each entry of the array. So you can only access the video inside the `<mat-list-item>`.

Comment: ... Now I feel dumb. Batajus was correct, I did not realize my ending tag for the mat-list-item was on the same line as the ngFor. Thank you all!